# Windows 10 recovery on Mac thinks GPT is MBR after resizing boot partition to the left with GParted

Tags: windows, mac

Running a 2015 MacBook Pro 13", Bootcamp was working with macOS and Windows 10 on the internal SSD with just the two JHFS+ and NTFS partitions. But Windows 10 was getting a little tight so I decided to adjust the partition sizes. I shrunk the Mac partition, creating blank space in between the Mac and NTFS partitions, and then used GParted Live USB to expand the NTFS partition into the empty space to its left, going from ~40GB to ~75GB, making sure that the boot flag was set.

Trying to boot Windows now just yields a blank black screen.

Using command prompt from Windows 10 recovery USB drive, I try to run the standard `bootrec` commands to repair, and while `bootrec /fixmbr` works, `bootrec /fixboot` and `bootrec /rebuildbcd` both give the error "Element not found".

Following [this guide](http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-uefi-bootloader-in-windows-8/) I tried using `diskpart` to make sure the volume is active and assign drive letters, but found out that Windows (or at least diskpart) thinks the drive is using MBR, even though it definitely is GPT (both macOS and GParted agree on this).

Any idea what's going on, how it happened, and how I can fix it?

EDIT:

As requested, here's screenshots of diskutil and diskpart:

[image: diskutil]

[image: diskpart]

Comment: There are all kinds of issues here. 1) You can't fix an MBR on a GPT diak… it doesn't have one. 2) Are you absolutely certain the volume was GPT and not Protected MBR. The problem there is if you check that in Windows, it can't tell, so it can get it wrong 7 completely gnarl your drive, especially with the dangerous move of trying to move 'left'. Right you can get away with, left can just overwrite things it's totally unaware exist. From macOS, please paste the details of `diskutil list` into your question.

Comment: I seem to remember that this is normal -- Boot Camp deliberately boots Windows in emulated "BIOS" mode, and it either lies to Windows about the partition table, or constructs a hybrid GPT which has real partitions within the MBR, or something like that? (Probably because in the past it used be aimed at booting Windows XP which did not have GPT support yet...)

Comment: @user1686 - it used to, it doesn't on more modern Macs. idk when it changed & don't have one of the newer EFI-based Boot Camp partitions to test.

Comment: I have to admit to not being completely certain what's happened, but the Mac definitely can't see that the Windows main BC partition exists at all. Diskpart, of course, can't see any of the Mac's APFS structure. I'm not sure where to head neaxt - however, as no-one else on SuperUser has picked up on your question yet, perhaps flag it to me migrated to Ask Different. There are some smart cookies on there with far better Mac-specific knowledge than me. Maybe someone there could help.

Comment: A 2015 MacBook Pro should have Windows 10 installed to EFI boot. This means the drive should not be hybrid partitioned. The drive should have pure GPT partitioning. All the Windows 10 boot files should reside in the EFI partition on the drive. This should be the first partition on the drive. The Windows command needed to create the Windows EFI boot files is called `bcdboot`. The parameters to the `bcdboot` command depend on the drive letter assignments you make using the `diskpart` command. These commands are accessible once booted from a ExFAT formatted Windows 10 USB flash drive installler.